# Is there a way to add a blank data attribute to an element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I want to create an element like the following with JavaScript:

```html
<div data-boolean-attribute></div>
```

Passing `null` or `undefined` to `setAttribute()` or the `dataset` property results in a value of the literal strings `'null'` and `'undefined'`. Passing an empty string or array to either method results in an empty string value:

```html
<div data-boolean-attribute=""></div>
```

Is it possible to create a completely empty data attribute in vanilla JavaScript **without** using something like `innerHTML`?

Comment: `setAttribute` is the only way. and data attributes are not boolean attributes. Even though you have some actual boolean attributes it is not invalid or wrong to assign them the value true such as `readonly="true"`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to do this?

Comment: Having an empty value or true/false etc are all valid and you can access them via javascript and CSS. So what is the specific reason why you don't want a value associated?

Comment: whats the point of setting a `data-attribute` if no value has to be associated to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, using both dataset and setAttribute lets you pass an empty string and it won't add a value.

```js
const test = document.querySelector("#test")
test.dataset.testa = "";
test.setAttribute("data-testB","");
console.log(test)
```

```html
<div id="test">TEST</div>
```

Comment: @tacoshy, which is odd. I get data attributes without the empty value. My results are exactly what they are looking for.

Comment: @tacoshy This does appear to work as intended in Chrome. I used Firefox for testing as I didn't expect behavior to vary across browsers. I also use they/them pronouns.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div element, then set data attr to empty string, and append it to the DOM body.

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.dataset.booleanAttribute = '';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```